# Using PHP script to create a web service on Free Web Hosting

Tags: java, php, web-services, ftp, cloud-hosting

I new to the development stuff here.
I would like to know whether is it possible to use PHP script to create a web service and run it on cloud hosting?
How about the web service I created using Java? Can it be ran on the cloud hosting as well?

Currently I am using a free cloud hosting from www.000webhost.com (Free Web Hosting).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You can **create a web-service in PHP**, on a free hosting provider. But in case of the free-webhosts, you don't get your dedicated machine to run your Java webservice on, so you will have to redesign the entire thing in PHP.

With free-hosting, you do run into limitations, so buying a hosting package is better.
A lot of them insert their own snippets of "**Powered by xxx Hosting**" strings into all your pages, that break any XML you are serving, so please keep that in mind.

(**[000webhost webservice potential issue](http://www.000webhost.com/forum/customer-assistance/29872-webservice.html)**)

Comment: if you look at the second post of the link you provide you can see that the analytics can be swithced off

Comment: Yes. Was just pointing out a potential issue with some webhosts.